# Imitating Controller Context For Razor View Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use the code below to render a Razor view template into a string:

```
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
    //var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, vd, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(new ControllerContext(), viewResult.View, vd, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    html = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

But since this will be invoked from a Web Api controller, how can I imitate and pass a valid MVC controller context for this to work?

Comment: why would you want to render a razor view in a web api controller ?

Comment: @Shyju raises a good point, give us the why you want to do this - there may be a better alternative.  The only time I've needed to do something like this was when using razor view to generate an email body, I used [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to achieve this.

Comment: @Shyju An example could be using Razor partial views that are then sent to a javascript which in turn insert them into an existing page. This is doable using Rick Strahl's ViewRenderer class if you have a proper HttpContext available. We've used this technique many times.

Comment: @Manfred It makes sense to do that in an MVC controller, Web Api controllers should be only serving data, not HTML markup :)

Comment: @shyju I see your point and agree, in particular where projects differentiate between the two. In a lot of our projects we no longer separate between mvc and api controllers in terms of base class. They all implement some method handling a request and return either HTML (view, partials, etc.) or data (json, xml, etc.). In general we tend to place "api" calls in a separate area.